# Binary Search Guessing Game

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I am trying to create a small program that uses binary search algorithm to have the computer itself guess a number given a set of arguments.

The arguments the function takes in are how many 'tries' it has to guess and the values that it can guess between (for example, 5 tries to guess the number in between 0 and 10).

When I run my code, it only seems to run my else: statement, regardless of the arguments I pass in.

I am missing something in my "if" statements but I am stumped and can't figure out what I have done incorrectly.

Thank you so much for your time and help!

```
import random

def guess_random_number_binary(tries, start, stop):
    
    rand_number = random.randint(start,stop)
    num_list = range(start,stop)

    lower_bound = start
    upper_bound = len(str(stop)) - 1
    
    while lower_bound <= upper_bound:
        pivot = (lower_bound + upper_bound) // 2
        pivot_value = num_list[pivot]
    
        if pivot_value == rand_number and tries > 0:
            print("Found it! " + str(rand_number))
            return pivot
        if pivot_value > rand_number and tries > 0:
            upper_bound = pivot - 1
            tries -= 1
            print ("incorrect guess" + str(tries) + " Remaining")
        else:
            lower_bound = pivot + 1
            print("Out of tries")
            return


guess_random_number_binary(5, 0 ,10)
```

UPDATE:

```
import random

def guess_random_number_binary(tries, start, stop):
    
    rand_number = random.randint(start,stop)    
    num_list = []

    lower_bound = start
    upper_bound = stop
    
    num_list = range(start,stop+1)
     
    while lower_bound <= upper_bound:
                
        pivot = (lower_bound + upper_bound) // 2
        pivot_value = num_list[pivot]

        if tries > 0:
            if pivot_value == rand_number:
                print("Found it! " + str(rand_number))
                return pivot
            elif pivot_value > rand_number:
                upper_bound = pivot - 1
                tries -= 1
                print ("Guessed " + str(pivot) + " incorrectly \n" +  str(tries) + " Tries remaining")
            elif pivot_value < rand_number:
                lower_bound = pivot + 1
                tries -= 1
                print ("Guessed " + str(pivot) + " incorrectly \n" +  str(tries) + " Tries remaining")
        else:
            print ("Ran out of tries!")
            break


guess_random_number_binary(5, 20 ,30)
```

I have been trying to debug and even if my new code is over simplified, I hope that it is at least headed in the right direction.

I believe the main issue stands with how I am creating "num_list" as pointed out by an answer below. Receiving an IndexError, which makes sense in theory. However, I cannot seem to find an alternative for creating that list.

Once again, thank you.

Comment: "When I run my code, it only seems to run my else: statement, regardless of the arguments I pass in." Why exactly do you think this is the case? Show an example of how you try to run the program, *exactly* what happens when you do so (i.e., what output you get), and *exactly* what is supposed to happen instead (and why). Next, try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code yourself, as is [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/). For example, does `pivot_value` have the value and type you expect? How about `rand_number` and `tries`?

Comment: Hint: Is it possible that `pivot_value == rand_number` while also `pivot_value > rand_number`? In the case where `pivot_value == rand_number`, what path do you expect to be taken through the code inside the loop? Why? Is something supposed to prevent the `else:` block from running when `pivot_value == rand_number`? How is that intended to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting the value of `pivot` at the beginning of each loop, so

You passed in the value `10` for `stop`. So in the line `upper_bound = len(str(stop)) - 1`,

upper_bound = len(str(stop))-1 = len(str(10) = len ('10')-1 = 1.

Your while loop never runs, because `lower_bound` is never less than `upper_bound`.

You perhaps were at some point intending to do `upper_bound = len(num_list)-1` and somehow wrote `upper_bound = len(str(stop)) - 1` instead. However, even that would not have been correct; the length of `range(start,stop)` is stop-start, not stop-start+1 (`range` is not inclusive of `stop`). And using `range` in the first place is unnecessarily confusing and would not work for larger `start` values. For instance, suppose `(start, stop) = (20, 30)`. Then `pivot` will be 25. But the `range` object will have only 10 elements, so `num_range[pivot]` will return an error.